# Binding and Validation on Blazor form over several components

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to separate a Blazor form into multiple components. The single version handles validation and binding. How do I do validation and binding on separate components? Do I use Cascading parameters, non-cascading parameters, cascading EditForm etc? There is a lot about Blazor but struggling to put it all together for this case.

Single person and address component:

```
<EditForm Model=@FormData>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText @bind-Value=FormData.FullName />
    <InputText @bind-Value=FormData.Address1 />
    <InputText @bind-Value=FormData.Address2 />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    PersonFullDataModel FormData = new PersonFullDataModel();
}
```

Single model:

```
public class PersonFullDataModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Separate Person component:

```
<EditForm Model=@FormData>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText @bind-Value=FormData.FullName />
    <ComponentAddress/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    PersonDataModel FormData = new PersonDataModel();
}
```

Separate Address component (ComponentAddress):

```
<InputText @bind-Value=FormData.Address1 />
<InputText @bind-Value=FormData.Address2 />

@code {
    AddressDataModel FormData = new AddressDataModel(); // this data does not go anywhere
}
```

Person model:

```
public class PersonDataModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public AddressDataModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

Address model:

```
public class AddressDataModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

- Use `<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />` and  `[ValidateComplexType]` attribute. [More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types).
- Use **FluentValidation**. [More information](https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/) or [Nuget package](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation).

I recommend to use fluent validation. More initial struggle, but complex validation is possible (and works fine on blazor client).

Comment: This does work and error messages for the sub-components are shown in the ValidationSummary. However if I add <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Value.Address1)" /> to my sub-component, the error message is not shown for an individual field

Comment: @user3807918 did you ever figure this out? I am trying to basically do the same thing. I'd like subcomponents (especially ones that are repeated) to have meaningful field messages on them.

Answer (score 1):

The `PersonFullDataModel` class should be changed so it contains 2 properties: `PersonDataModel` and `AddressDataModel`. They have to be instanciated in the parent component.

In `ComponentAddress`, you shoud create a parameter:

```
[Parameter]
public PersonFullDataModel PersonFullData { get; set; }
```

In the address component, you change the binding to `PersonFullData.AddressData.Address1` and `PersonFullData.AddressData.Address2`.

As the `PersonFullData` parameter is passed by reference from your main component to the single component, it is usable on both sides.